# Ansible python version won't change

Tags: python, ansible

I'm executing:

`ansible-playbook --version`

And I get the following output:

```
ansible-playbook 2.5.14
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'~/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 2.7.12 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:36:49) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
```

But when I execute:

`ansible-playbook --version -e 'ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3'`

I'm having exactly the same output. I was expecting having something like:

```
python version = 3.5.2
```

What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To change the python interpreter used on a managed host you can either use an extra or inventory variable, as per your question. This does not change the version of python used to execute ansible locally - which is mentioned in the other answer.

To confirm that you are using a different interpreter on the managed host, you will need more verbose output (at least 3 'v's, `-vvv`). Running `python --version` in a shell command is just going to show you what the system's default python version is.

**Example**

Python2 interpreter:

```
$ ansible localhost -a 'python --version' -e 'ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python2' -vvv
ansible 2.8.1
<snip>
  python version = 3.7.3 (default, May 11 2019, 00:38:04) [GCC 9.1.1 20190503 (Red Hat 9.1.1-1)]
<snip>
'/bin/sh -c '"'"'/usr/bin/python2 /home/mattp/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1564023345.0848873-106174541151316/AnsiballZ_command.py && sleep 0'"'"''
<snip>
localhost | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
Python 2.7.16
```

Python3 interpreter:

```
$ ansible localhost -a 'python --version' -e 'ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3' -vvv
ansible 2.8.1
<snip>
  python version = 3.7.3 (default, May 11 2019, 00:38:04) [GCC 9.1.1 20190503 (Red Hat 9.1.1-1)]
<snip>
'/bin/sh -c '"'"'/usr/bin/python3 /home/mattp/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1564023350.3869421-223113472194736/AnsiballZ_command.py && sleep 0'"'"''
<snip>
localhost | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
Python 2.7.16
```

**Key takeaways**

- The python version used to run Ansible locally remains unchanged
- The system default python version remains unchanged
- The python version used to execute the Ansible command module remotely (i.e. the python interpreter) has changed from version 2 to 3

Comment: I have re-checked the logs and it seems that the `ansible_python_interpreter` was well taken into account when using it in the host inventory, I was just confused about having the unchanged version as you said in your keys 1 and 2.

Answer (score 3):

Other workaround is to specify var `ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3` in your playbook as in my case sometimes ansible doesn't take interpreter from `ansible.cfg` file.

Example:

```
- name: Common package
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
  roles:
    - { role: python, tags: [ init, python, common, addusers] }
...
...
```

Now at every run playbook will take `/usr/bin/python3` as default interpreter.

NOTE: if you want to use python2.7 then you can change python3 to python and it should work fine. [FYI python2.7 will be deprecated from January 2020]

Comment: Same for me, it worked to use it in the inventory or the playbook, but not in `ansible.cfg` in Ansible `2.11.4`.

Answer (score 2):

`ansible-playbook` is a software installed on your computer, with its own dependencies, you can't change its dependencies with an argument - you should install a suitable version for that.

With that argument you're changing the Python interpreter on the remote host, one or multiple, that playbook deals with.

Comment: `With that argument you're changing the Python interpreter on the remote host`that's exactly what I want to do, how can I test then if I am effectivily changing the python interpreter on the remote host?

Comment: Try with running task `command: python --version` having `register: python_version` in it, and then another task `- debug: msg="{{ python_version.stdout }}"`.

Comment: Thank you, I can confirm that it is using python2.7 even when I set `ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3`. I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Comment: I believe that argument is just for setting the **path** to Python 2, that is the Python version your Ansible is understanding and using - it simply doesn't output an error when fallbacks to default after not excepting your python3 directive.

Comment: You can't change the interpreter with an extra variable. Try appending it to your host in the inventory - eg. `my_host ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3`

Comment: @MattP Still using python2 :(

Comment: Hmm .. turns out you can set the interpreter with an extra variable - learn something new every day. I'll add an appropriate answer as I'm pretty sure I know what is going on.