# Cannot change Python version in ansible

Tags: python, ansible

When I run the following command: `ansible-playbook --version`, I get the results:

```
ansible-playbook 2.5.0
  config file = /home/dev/sources/Installation/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 3.8.10 (default, Jun  2 2021, 10:49:15) [GCC 9.4.0]
```

**The thing is that I'd like Python 2.7.8 in the location instead of 3.8.10.**

I configured the `ansible.cfg` file as follows:

```
[defaults]
# SSH key host checking
host_key_checking=false
allow_world_readable_tmpfiles=true
roles_path=./roles/:../../Installation/roles/
filter_plugins=./filter_plugins/:../../Installation/filter_plugins/
ansible_python_interpreter=/opt/Python-2.7.8/python/
ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
```

... and when I run the `ansible-playbook --version` command again, it still points to Python 3.8. What am I doing wrong? I also tried to define python variable in playbook vars (`ansible_python_interpreter: /opt/Python-2.7.8/python/)`, however without the success.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ansible python version won't change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57167091/ansible-python-version-wont-change)

Comment: just like in the above link's answer mentioned, you need to tell this in your playbook `vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3` ..in your case that path is for `Python-2.7.8`

Comment: I provided this variable in the playbook and this doesn't work..

Comment: You are mixing up the python version used by the controller (i.e. reported by `ansible --version`) and the one used on the target (i.e. discovered or configured in ansible.cfg, inventory, playbook...). To change the first, reinstall Ansible in the desired python version.

Comment: If you can to set this through `ansible.cfg` you need to use `interpreter_python` ,  `ansible_python_interpreter ` can be used only in variables, see [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#interpreter-python)

Answer (score 2):

**ansible** is a **python package** that consists of a couple of executables like `ansible`, `ansible-playbook`, `ansible-galaxy`. If you want to use Python 2.7 then you should ensure that ansible is installed as a library for that python, and that the executables of that install are in your PATH variable etc. One way to do that is by using `virtualenv`, which creates a copy of Python 2.7 that you can activate just for that project of yours. python-virtualenv is a package for your operating system. Once you've installed it you can run:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 py27
source py27/bin/activate
pip install ansible==2.5.0
ansible-playbook --version
```

**Please note that Python 2.7 was EOL January 1, 2020, and Ansible 2.8 and earlier are outdated and are no longer updated by the community. (Although still supported by some vendors)**